# How to write a test project with dependency to a ASP.Net/PHP project?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

lets say I have three projects in my solution.

1 Is a ASP.Net project simply printing an output

2 Is a PHP project using VS.PHP which simply prints an output (Same output as the ASP.Net project. Just in different environment)

3 A C# Console project which use the above two projects as server and parse their responses.

Now I want to add an other project named "Test" and fill it with unit tests mainly for testing the integrity of the solution. 
I am new to unit tests but my main problem here is not about them. It is about this simple question that: How can I run the two first projects (Using VS.Php Webserver for PHP and IIS Express for ASP.Net project - one at each time) somehow before performing my tests? I cant test the 3rd project without having one of the first two active and in result I cant check the integrity of my project. Not even parts of it.

So, do you have any suggestion? Am I wrong about something here? Maybe I just don't understand something.

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for unit testing you don't connect live systems together with your tests. That would be called integration testing instead. The line I usually use with unit testing is that it needs to a) always be fast and b) be able to be run without network connectivity.

If you want to do unit testing, the easiest way is to make interfaces around your dependent systems. Don't use these names, but something like IAspNetProject and IPhpProject. Code to those interfaces and then replace their implementation with fake data for unit testing.

If you want to do integration testing, then you can use something like http://nancyfx.org/ to create a self hosted web project. There are tons of other options for starting a lightweight web app locally to do testing against.

Comment: I see, but can VS help me with the integration testings? In my scenario a small change in the projects can break the integrity of the solution. So I need to run tests frequency. Unfortunately I cant go with Mock Data suggestion either as the project it-self is a networking project :D

Comment: Yeah you can write tests with the Visual Studio testing framework and they can be integration tests. You can also write a console app to test the code. From my experience integration testing is more open ended. I would invest the time then to create mock environments. Dummy servers that run locally that can accept connections etc.

Comment: Writing a Console App is the way to go in my case probably. Thanks for mentioning that. And yeah I already have some tests against a local server, just wanted to have more test against a real one.